# Stack Navigator in React Native. Error "undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation)"

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined, react-navigation, stack-navigator

It's taking me forever to figure out the obvious, would appreciate some help.

Im using a stack navigator, when a button is pressed it will simply go to another page.

In app.js I created a stack navigator:

```
const Switcher = createStackNavigator(
  {
    TaskPg: ListScreen,
    AboutPg: AboutScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "TaskPg",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'BlueList'
    }
  }
)
```

In the ListScreen there is a button the user can press to go to the about page.

```
const ListScreen = () => {


    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            {/* add task component with date picker */}
            <AddItemModel />

            {/* button pressed to goto About Screen */}
            <Button
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(AboutScreen)}
                title="About App" />

            {/* sign out button linked to firebase log out */}
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()} >
                <Text style={styles.button} >Sign Out</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    );

}

export default ListScreen
```

Run code and every time I press the button I get the error undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation)

Comment: Can you post the rest of your render logic for ListScreen?

Comment: I just added everything except the imports and styles

Comment: "undefined is not object" error is an JavaScript bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your ListScreen is a functional component, `this.props` doesn't  exist.

Change your ListScreen declaration to:

```
const ListScreen = props => {...}
```

and access your navigation object like this:

```
props.navigation.navigate(AboutScreen);
```